# How can I demangle a Swift class name dynamically?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios8

I'm aware of the swift-demangle command line utility. I'm looking for something that will let me do this from Swift itself.

I got excited when I saw this after running `:target modules dump symtab` from the Swift REPL, but I don't know how to call `swift_demangleSimpleClass`.

[image: module dump]

It seems that there's an `@asmname` command that would allow calling private Swift functions, but I haven't been able to get that to work.

I'll probably just end up writing a regex-based parser for this, but calling something in the Swift framework itself seems a bit safer.

Comment: I'll be parsing this manually for the time being. Code: https://gist.github.com/jpsim/1b86d116808cb4e9bc30

Answer (score 9):

**Swift 5**

You can use Swift's `swift_demangle` function to demangle names but it's not exported by default so you need to import first:

```swift
import Darwin

typealias Swift_Demangle = @convention(c) (_ mangledName: UnsafePointer<UInt8>?,
                                           _ mangledNameLength: Int,
                                           _ outputBuffer: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>?,
                                           _ outputBufferSize: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int>?,
                                           _ flags: UInt32) -> UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>?

func swift_demangle(_ mangled: String) -> String? {
    let RTLD_DEFAULT = dlopen(nil, RTLD_NOW)
    if let sym = dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, "swift_demangle") {
        let f = unsafeBitCast(sym, to: Swift_Demangle.self)
        if let cString = f(mangled, mangled.count, nil, nil, 0) {
            defer { cString.deallocate() }
            return String(cString: cString)
        }
    }
    return nil
}

// How to use
if let s = swift_demangle("$s20MyPlayground_Sources4TestC4testSSyF") {
    print(s) // MyPlayground_Sources.Test.test() -> Swift.String
}
```

Comment: Would this pass AppStore review?

Comment: @Dale I use this code inside my swift package which is included to my app and have no claims from App Store about.

Answer (score 3):

```
func typename (thing:Any) -> String{
    let name = _stdlib_getTypeName(thing)
    let demangleName = _stdlib_demangleName(name)
    return demangleName.componentsSeparatedByString(".").last!
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing. Have you found an alternative to that?

Answer (score 3):

At the moment (XCode 6 plus 7 beta) for classes at the highest level you just get your appname plus a dot plus your classname. So it will be something like MyApp.MyClass But the moment you are using sub classes, the description is build up in the following 3 sections:

1. The description starts with _Tt which stands for target (bundle / app name)
2. After that you will have one or more letters like C P F which stands for Class, Protocol or Function. These are in reverse order according to the nesting
3. Then you will get series of numbers plus a name where the number is the length of the name. each of these are for the target, Class, Protocol or Function as specified in the beginning of the description.

Functions are a special case here. The description will also has some information about the function signature.

For example you could have a _TtCFCC5MyApp7MyClass10MySubClass6myFuncFS0_FT_T_L_11MySubSubClass

This would be the description of the MySubSubClass in the following code:

```
class MyClass {
   class MySubClass {
     func myFunc() {
       class MySubSubClass {
       }
     }
   }
}
```

Here you can find some [sample code](https://github.com/evermeer/EVReflection/blob/68edace301602dd43181075c604a1f987185be3f/EVReflection/pod/EVObjectDescription.swift#L14-14) that will parse that description into easy to use properties and arrays.

Update: Demangle is now converted to swift. You can find it here: https://github.com/mattgallagher/CwlDemangle/blob/master/CwlDemangle/CwlDemangle.swift

Comment: Should that say "_TtCCFC..." instead of "_TtCFCC..."?

Comment: No, the order is correct. As I said in point 2 they are in reversed order.

Answer (score -1):

**Update:** as of XCode6 beta 5, NSStringFromClass seems to return demangled class names automatically, so this code should no longer be needed.

There should be a built-in way to do this, but until there is, this extension should do the trick:

```
import Foundation

public func demangleClassName(mangled: String) -> String {
    let scanner = NSScanner(string: mangled)
    if (!scanner.scanString("_TtC", intoString: nil)) {
        // not a mangled swift class name: Core Foundation, etc. have no module prefix
        return mangled
    }

    var demangled = ""
    var len : Int = 0
    while (!scanner.atEnd && scanner.scanInteger(&len)) {
        let range = Range(start:advance(mangled.startIndex, scanner.scanLocation), end: advance(mangled.startIndex, scanner.scanLocation + len))
        let part = mangled.substringWithRange(range)
        if (countElements(demangled) > 0) {
            demangled += "."
        }
        demangled += part
        scanner.scanLocation += len // skip to the next segment that may be prefixed by the number
    }

    return demangled
}

public extension NSObject {
    /// demangle the current Swift object's class name, as per mangling description at: http://www.eswick.com/2014/06/inside-swift/
    public class func demangledClassName() -> String {
        return demangleClassName(className())
    }
}
```

Comment: Except that that code doesn't compile. See my further comments on your gist (https://gist.github.com/mprudhom/69ec96f3d95c3d080e6a)

Comment: It works fine for me, both in a module and in the Playground in XCode 6 beta 3. If you open the playground and paste it in, what error do you see?

Comment: I never use playgrounds. I pasted it into an app and `className()` in the first line wasn't recognized.

Comment: That's why it needs to be an extension on NSObject: only NSObject has className().

Comment: It was an extension on NSObject in your gist. I pasted your entire gist into the top level of one of my Swift class files. In the line `return demangleClassName(className())` we choke on `className()`. Where is it that you imagine this function comes from? I've never heard of it (not that that proves anything, but I have been doing this for quite a long time).

Comment: Are you using beta3? And the code "let cn = NSString.className()" doesn't compile for you? Weird. You could just replace it with "NSStringFromClass(self)" I suppose.