# Apple Swift mangling rules for recurring context

Tags: swift, abi, name-mangling

On MacOS with Swift 5.6 and given the [mangling rules from here](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/docs/ABI/Mangling.rst) with the following Swift code:

```
class Car //AB
{
    class Foo //AD
    {
        func Foo() -> Void //AD
        {
               
        }
    }
}
```

The resulting mangled name for `Foo` is `_$s4TEST3CarC3FooCADyyF` (Target name `TEST`), I cannot understand why `Foo` is given the index code `AD`, I would expect `AC` to be assigned:

```
AA   AB  AC 
TEST.Car.Foo.Foo
```

In this other example:

```
class TEST //AA
{
    class Car //AC
    {
        class Foo //AE
        {
            class Car //AC
            {
                func Foo() -> Void //AE
                {
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The mangled name is `_$s4TESTAAC3CarC3FooCACCAEyyF`, again those are the values I would assign:

```
AA        AB  AC
TEST.TEST.Car.Foo.Car.Foo
```

Why `Foo` is assigned to `AE` after the first long form encoding `3Foo`? Why `AB` and `AD` are skipped and not used? Note that this is only in regards to recurrent items in the string, if the are no recurrent items i can encode all happily.

Comment: I think this question should be asked at https://forums.swift.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first case, the substitution indices are assigned as follows:

```
AA TEST
AB Car
AC TEST.Car
AD Foo
AE TEST.Car.Foo
```

You can get these results by using the demangling code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24321773/how-can-i-demangle-a-swift-class-name-dynamically). Demangle the mangled name of the method, just without the `F` suffix - this is to allow us to add any `A` substitution of our choice to the end. (I've also removed the `yy` to reduce noise in the output)

```
print(swift_demangle("$s4TEST3CarC3FooCAdA")!)
print(swift_demangle("$s4TEST3CarC3FooCAdB")!)
print(swift_demangle("$s4TEST3CarC3FooCAdC")!)
print(swift_demangle("$s4TEST3CarC3FooCAdD")!)
print(swift_demangle("$s4TEST3CarC3FooCAdE")!)
/*
TEST.Car.FooFooTEST
TEST.Car.FooFooCar
TEST.Car.FooFooTEST.Car
TEST.Car.FooFooFoo
TEST.Car.FooFooTEST.Car.Foo
*/
```

So it turns out that, when the mangling algorithm mangles `Car`, it also "remembers" a substitution for `TEST.Car` (because it is a nominal type, perhaps), not just `Car` on its own. This happens regardless of whether the substitution is used later on or not, probably to make demangling easier (?)

You can also see this in effect when you change the code to:

```
class Car
{
    class Foo
    {
        func Foo() -> Car
        {
            fatalError("")
        }
    }
}
```

Now the method `Foo`'s mangled name is `$s6output3CarC3FooCAdCyF`, making use of `AC`.

As a mental model, you can think of it as the substitution indices being associated with the letter `C` in the mangled name as well as the `<number><identifier>` parts, like this:

```
$s4TEST3CarC3FooCADyyF
   ^     ^ ^  ^ ^
   |     | |  | |
  AA     ABAC ADAE
```

A similar thing happens in the second case. `AB` is `TEST.TEST` and `AD` is `TEST.TEST.Car`.