# Getting symbol not found error after GCC address sanitization enabled

Tags: c, gcc, linker, openwrt, address-sanitizer

I compiled my binary with `-fsanitize=address` option in `OpenWRT` build environment with GCC version `7.5.0` to find the possible memory leaks in the application. There are no issues faced during cross compilation. While running the executable in target environment, I got `symbol not found` error.

**GCC Details:**
aarch64-openwrt-linux-musl-gcc (OpenWrt GCC 7.5.0 r11-afafb2b1c) 7.5.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
**LIBC** : MUSL libc

**Makefile changes:**
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -Os -g -Wall --std=gnu99 `-fsanitize=address -fno-omit-frame-pointer`")
NUSPD_DEPENDS := +libuci +libubox +libubus +libblobmsg-json +cfgmgr +libjson-c libixml +libcurl +idl2json +obj2json `+libasan`

**Program execution fails:**

```
root@Bean10:/home/superadmin# Nuspd  
**get cfg_loadRemoteCfgs fail:Symbol not found: swift_demangle**

root@Bean10:/home/superadmin# ldd --list /sbin/Nuspd | grep -i asan  
        libasan.so.4 => /usr/lib/libasan.so.4 (0x7f7fcc8000) 

root@Bean10:/home/superadmin# ls /usr/lib/libasan.so* -lh  
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root          16 Jun 27 17:44 /usr/lib/libasan.so -> libasan.so.4.0.0  
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root          16 Jun 27 17:44 /usr/lib/libasan.so.4 -> libasan.so.4.0.0  
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root      905.7K Jun 27 17:44 /usr/lib/libasan.so.4.0.0
```

root@Bean10:/home/superadmin#

Here the symbol `cfg_loadRemoteCfgs` is part of libcfg.so shared library which my binary is already linked to.

**strace output:**

```
--- SIGILL {si_signo=SIGILL, si_code=ILL_ILLOPC, si_addr=0x7fb962f690} ---
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, ~[ILL TRAP BUS FPE KILL SEGV STOP RTMIN RT_1 RT_2], NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, NULL, ~[ILL TRAP BUS FPE KILL SEGV STOP RTMIN RT_1 RT_2], 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGILL, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7fbad42e90}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2097152, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fb6200000
munmap(0x7fb6300000, 1048576)           = 0
mmap(NULL, 2097152, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fb6000000
munmap(0x7fb6100000, 1048576)           = 0
mmap(NULL, 2097152, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fb5e00000
munmap(0x7fb5f00000, 1048576)           = 0
writev(2, [{iov_base="get cfg_loadRemoteCfgs fail:Symb"..., iov_len=61}, {iov_base=NULL, iov_len=0}], 2get cfg_loadRemoteCfgs fail:Symbol not found: swift_demangle
) = 61
```

My question is why after introducing GCC address sanitizer option, the linker is not able to find the symbols during run time.

**With ASAN/LSAN verbosity enabled:**

```
root@Bean10:/home/superadmin# LSAN_OPTIONS=verbosity=1:log_threads=1 Nuspd
==10901==LeakSanitizer: Dynamic linker not found. TLS will not be handled correctly.
==10901==AddressSanitizer Init done
get cfg_loadRemoteCfgs fail:Symbol not found: swift_demangle
==10902==Processing thread 10901.
==10902==Stack at 0x007ff5a57000-0x007ff6257000 (SP = 0x007ff6255fc0).
==10902==TLS at 0x000000000000-0x000000000000.
```

Expecting some help in this area.

Comment: Perhaps related to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24321773/how-can-i-demangle-a-swift-class-name-dynamically

Comment: This is probaably caused by cfg_loadRemoteCfgs trying to load a shared library with dlopen. You can try to find out which library by using `strace` and looking for the last attempt to open a `.so` file.

Comment: @n.m.willseey'allonReddit - Thanks for suggesting `strace`. I am seeing `SIGILL` and lot of `munmap` in strace and not `dlopen` calls.

Comment: @n.m.willseey'allonReddit - I have updated strace and ASAN verbose logs in the description. Kindly comment.

Comment: Not sure I can understand anything here. Dynamic linker not found? Never saw this one.