# Print Function Call Stack in Swift?

Tags: swift, callstack

I'm attempting to print a function call stack in a Swift function. I'm using Swift v5.9 on a Windows 10 system.

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30754796/how-to-print-call-stack-in-swift) and many others, I should use the `callStackSymbols` field to acquire my call stack.

I have the following example code:

```
import Foundation

func test()
{
    print(Thread.callStackSymbols)
}

test()
```

Compiling & running the code above produces the following output:

```
["$s10Foundation6ThreadC16callStackSymbolsSaySSGvgZ\0", "", "", "", "BaseThreadInitThunk\0", "RtlUserThreadStart\0"]
```

It is my understanding that this is a sequence of some sort of symbols, but I don't quite understand what they're supposed to represent. I'm assuming they're symbols standing in for the function names.

How do I print a function call stack in Swift, and parse the stack symbols to correspond to my function names?

Thanks for reading my post, any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Windows, but if you can do whatever the equivalent of `dlopen`/`dlsym` is in Windows, you can adapt [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67107537/5133585). If you can launch a subprocess, you can also launch `swift demangle --compact <insert name here>` and read its stdout.